# Как настроить в Sublime 3 автоформатирование кода

Tags: sublime-text, sublime-text-3

Как настроить в Sublime 3 автоформатирование кода?

Допустим, я вставил HTML код в Sublime Text. Этот код с одинаковой табуляцией, соответственно, получается каша.

Как сделать так, чтобы при определённом действии код сам форматировался и принимал нормальный вид?

```
                  <form>
             <div>
        <div></div>
        <div>
            <div>
             <img>
         </div>
         <div>
            <input>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: Установите https://github.com/victorporof/Sublime-HTMLPrettify

Comment: Да, только ты забыл, что нужно с false в конце поменять на true?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

### Стандартными средствами

`Preferences` → `Key Bindings — User`

Если файл пустой, то вставить код полностью.
Если нет, то добавить объект в массив, как добавляли бы его в JSON.

```
[
    { "keys": ["ctrl+alt+l"], "command": "reindent", "args": { "single_line": false } }
]
```

Данный код позволяет по нажатию комбинации <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> отформатировать код во всем файле или только внутри выделенного фрагмента.

---

### С помощью стороннего плагина

Есть плагин [Sublime-HTMLPrettify](https://github.com/victorporof/Sublime-HTMLPrettify). Ему нужен установленный [node.js](http://nodejs.org/#download) для работы.
Может читать настройки из `.jsbeautifyrc` файла.

**Установка**:

- Нажмите <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> или <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> в Linux/Windows/OS X
- Наберите `install`, выберите `Package Control: Install Package`
- Наберите `prettify`, выберите `HTML-CSS-JS Prettify`

**Использование** (любой из вариантов)

- Выберите `Tools` → `Command Palette` (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> или <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>) и наберите `htmlprettify`.
- Нажмите <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> (или <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> если у вас Mac).
- Кликните правой кнопкой мыши на выделенном фрагменте `HTML/CSS/JS Prettify` → `Prettify Code`
- Откройте HTML, CSS или JavaScript file, откройте консоль Sublime Text через меню `View` → `Show Console` и наберите `view.run_command("htmlprettify")`.

Пример работы на вашем фрагменте кода:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: нормально не форматирует. Не форматирует, двигает, но не форматирует.

Comment: @ЮрийСветлов Пример кода, который надо отформатировать скиньте, пожалуйста

Comment: Вот, пожалуйста. Обновил свой вопрос.

Comment: @ЮрийСветлов, я обновил свой ответ