# Автоматическая иерархия тегов в HTML

Tags: html

Имеется ли какой-нибудь скрипт в какой-нибудь среде программирования или что-то подобное, где автоматически иерархия тегов в HTML ставится? Выделил, нажал, и все само красиво встало)

Comment: Вы наверное имеете ввиду форматирование документа? Автоматическое форматирование доступно в большинстве редакторов.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это называется форматирование кода (да да HTML не код, а разметка)

Если нужно по быстрому в онлайне, то [вот](https://www.freeformatter.com/html-formatter.html)

Если в самом редакторе, то это уже зависит от него самого.

Для webstorm и вообще всех продуктов intellij, выбираете в меню "reformat code" или "reformat file"
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В Sublime Text можно [так](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/498667/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2-sublime-3-%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0)

Если ничего из этого то открываете гугл и пишете "<Ваш крутой редактор> formatting HTML" или "<Ваш крутой редактор> formatting code". Уверен узнаете много полезного :)

Comment: Идеально, спасибо, а то не знал я таких простых вещей.

Comment: Если ответ вам подходит, то отметьте его как верный (галочка). Тут так принято :)