# Плагин для выравнивания кода Sublime Text 3

Tags: sublime-text-3, плагин, выравнивание

У Brackets есть отличный плагин Beautify который выравнивает весь код как по вертикали, так и по горизонтали, делая его более читабельным.

Есть ли такой плагин для Sublime Text 3?

Обычные встроенные команды для выравнивания не подходят.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как настроить в Sublime 3 автоформатирование кода](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/498667/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2-sublime-3-%d0%b0%d0%b2%d1%82%d0%be%d1%84%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0)